# This is my ajax call but in this success function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am using a ajax call in my code. But in this ajax call the success function not working.

Below is the code I am using:

```
var data1 = { "name": namedata[0], "email": namedata[1], "mobile": namedata[2], "company": namedata[3], "message": namedata[4], };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data1,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
        $('#myModalSuccess').css('display', 'block');

        $('.close').click(function () {
            $('#myModalSuccess').css('display', 'none');
        });

    },
    error: function () {
        $('#myModalFail').css('display', 'block');

        $('.close').click(function () {
            $('#myModalFail').css('display', 'none');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell what data you are getting from the ***server*** as the ***response***?   Also, did you check inside ```sucess: function(data) { //your code } ``` what data are you getting? Try ```console.log(data)``` instead of ```alert("success");```

Comment: Add breakpoints in success and error functions and check where the execution goes and what response you get. Add it to your question as it will help others to your question.

Comment: how @NotABot said first check response with console.log(data) in success function if nothing coming back than check your url file why is not sending data

Comment: @Ivan Yes, mostly the error would be in ***server*** file, as this javascript code seems to be fine. The other thing can be done as precautionary is ```error:function(err){ console.log(err); } ``` if there are any javascript/network errors.

Comment: Needs more info/diagnostics/debugging, just "it's not working" doesn't help anyone - https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: First step - what do you see in browser devtools? Inspect the network request, is it send with params as expected?  Does server respond as expected? `not working` is not enough info for us to help - what happened? Some errors? Edit your question and add details.

Answer (score 0):

In error callback print the error in console.log() like below so that you will be able to identify the exact error-

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data1,
success: function (data) {
    alert("success");
    $('#myModalSuccess').css('display', 'block');

    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('#myModalSuccess').css('display', 'none');
    });

},
error: function (err) {
console.log(err)

    $('#myModalFail').css('display', 'block');

    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('#myModalFail').css('display', 'none');
    });
}});
```